# Add a bicycle with Aerolineas Argentinas

Tags: air-travel, bicycles

I've booked a flight LYS -> FRA -> EZE -> USH on Lufthansa website. The first two flights are operated by Lufthansa, so I was able to call their customer service and add a bicycle on my ticket. The last leg is operated by Aerolineas Argentinas, and the Lufthansa's customer service told me to contact them to add the bicycle.

On [Aerolinas Argentineas website](https://www.aerolineas.com.ar/en-ar/contacto/contactoreserva) they give a phone number for "international calls outside Argentina"; as I don't speak spanish, I guess I'd need that. But it doesn't work.

How can I tell Aerolineas Argentinas that I will have a bike with me?

EDIT: I can't use the contact form on their website as it asks for a booking number. My booking number is from Lufthansa and is not valid for Aerolinas.

Comment: Remember to box your bicycle. Lufthansa can accept bicycles as-is on many of their flights, but most other airlines cannot.

Comment: Were you calling from inside or outside Argentina?

Comment: Outside, but I was using the international number with the Argentinian prefix.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Spanish web page of Aerolineas Argentinas](https://www.aerolineas.com.ar/es-ar/equipaje/especial) you have this information:

[image]

That means that you can have a conventional bicycle with 1 seat, without motor and a container for the transportation. You would need to remove the pedals, fold the handlebars and deflat the tires.

Also for the special equipment an additional fee applies:

[image]

The web does not say anything about how to add it to your ticket, so probably when you do the check-in or at the counter in the airport.

**Edited:**

In this [link](https://www.aerolineas.com.ar/frequently-asked-questions-results?subcategory=282&question=277) you have:

[image]

Equipaje adicional (Additional luggage) 
¿Cómo puedo abonar el servicio? (How can I pay?) 
You can call to the contact center 0810-222-86527

An in [this one](https://www.aerolineas.com.ar/es-bo/contacto/sucursalesaeropuertos) you can search the office or the airport and you have a contact phone number.

I have seen that the main phone number is this:

[image]

Comment: I was aware of that. But according to the Lufthansa guy I spoke to (and to what I read online), I should tell them beforehand because the plane is not that big and I have to make sure they can take my bike.

Comment: It is an airline, so I don't think you will have a problem talking in English!

Comment: Yes! But HOW do I contact them??

Comment: I have edited the post to add the information I've found